# Jquery: How to remove duplicate HTML TABLE rows based on columns values

Tags: jquery

Using J-query,  how can i remove duplicate rows whose two columns values are repeated, eg. I have 2 columns i.e CA and STATUS, I want to consider unique row to be visible if the STATUS column value is 'PARTIAL' and the CA columns are duplicate.

**Current screen:**
[image: image 1]
**Expected Output screen:**

[image]

[CODE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wwLb9n46/)

**html code**

```
 <html>
   <HEAD> 
   </HEAD>
   <BODY class="lytBody">
      <FORM name="form0" method="post">
         <TABLE class="lytTable" border="0" bordercolor="#efefef">
            <TR>
               <TD class="lytM"> 
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td class="lytM">
                     <table border="1">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td width="6%" nowrap="nowrap" class="rsDsc">CA</td>
                              <td width="6%" nowrap="nowrap" class="rsDsc">LD</td>
                              <td width="6%" nowrap="nowrap" class="rsDsc">COUNT</td>
                              <td width="16%" nowrap="nowrap" class="rsDsc">NAME</td>
                              <td width="15%" nowrap="nowrap" class="rsDsc">DATE1</td>
                              <td width="10%" nowrap="nowrap" class="rsDsc">STATUS</td>
                              <td width="24%" nowrap="nowrap" class="rsDsc">DATE2</td>
                              <td width="29%" nowrap="nowrap" class="rsDsc">DATE3</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">BDC</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">5861</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle"></td>
                              <td width="16%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">ABC</td>
                              <td width="15%" class="rsData1">09/12/2011 04:33:20</td>
                              <td width="10%" class="rsData1">
                                 <div align="center"><input type="button" name="loadStatus" valign="middle" size="10" value="PENDING" onclick="javascript:getDetail('BDC','5861', 'PENDING')" class="PENDING"></div>
                              </td>
                              <td width="24%" class="rsData1"><br>
                              </td>
                              <td width="29%" class="rsData1">
                                 09/12/2011 04:33:55                                                
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">BDC</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">21990</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">1357</td>
                              <td width="16%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">DEF</td>
                              <td width="15%" class="rsData2">06/11/2015 11:37:58</td>
                              <td width="10%" class="rsData2">
                                 <div align="center"><input type="button" name="loadStatus" style="background-color:yellow;" valign="middle" size="10" value="PARTIAL" onclick="javascript:getDetail('BDC','21990','PARTIAL')" class="PARTIAL"></div>
                              </td>
                              <td width="24%" class="rsData2"> <br>
                                 06/11/2015 16:04:28
                              </td>
                              <td width="29%" class="rsData2">
                                 06/11/2015 16:04:28                                                
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">BDC</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">22366</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle"></td>
                              <td width="16%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">GHI</td>
                              <td width="15%" class="rsData1">07/29/2015 13:49:25</td>
                              <td width="10%" class="rsData1">
                                 <div align="center"><input type="button" name="loadStatus" valign="middle" size="10" value="PENDING" onclick="javascript:getDetail('BDC','22366', 'PENDING')" class="PENDING"></div>
                              </td>
                              <td width="24%" class="rsData1"><br>
                              </td>
                              <td width="29%" class="rsData1">
                                 07/29/2015 14:28:16                                                
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">BDC</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">22367</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">1357</td>
                              <td width="16%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">JKL</td>
                              <td width="15%" class="rsData2">07/29/2015 14:35:19</td>
                              <td width="10%" class="rsData2">
                                 <div align="center"><input type="button" name="loadStatus" valign="middle" size="10" value="PARTIAL" style="background-color:yellow;" onclick="javascript:getDetail('BDC','22367','PARTIAL')" class="PARTIAL"></div>
                              </td>
                              <td width="24%" class="rsData2"> <br>
                                 07/29/2015 15:03:37
                              </td>
                              <td width="29%" class="rsData2">
                                 07/29/2015 15:03:37                                                
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">BDC</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">22369</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">1357</td>
                              <td width="16%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">MNO</td>
                              <td width="15%" class="rsData1">07/29/2015 15:14:52</td>
                              <td width="10%" class="rsData1">
                                 <div align="center"><input type="button" name="loadStatus" valign="middle" size="10" value="PARTIAL" style="background-color:yellow;" onclick="javascript:getDetail('BDC','22369','PARTIAL')" class="PARTIAL"></div>
                              </td>
                              <td width="24%" class="rsData1">
                                 07/29/2015 15:52:46
                              </td>
                              <td width="29%" class="rsData1">
                                 07/29/2015 15:52:46                                                
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">BEX</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">9500</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle"></td>
                              <td width="16%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">PQR</td>
                              <td width="15%" class="rsData2">01/31/2012 00:39:57</td>
                              <td width="10%" class="rsData2">
                                 <div align="center"><input type="button" name="loadStatus" valign="middle" size="10" value="PENDING" onclick="javascript:getDetail('BEX','9500', 'PENDING')" class="PENDING"></div>
                              </td>
                              <td width="24%" class="rsData2"><br>
                              </td>
                              <td width="29%" class="rsData2">
                                 01/31/2012 00:40:58                                                
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">BID</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">9918</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData1" valign="middle"></td>
                              <td width="16%" class="rsData1" valign="middle">STW</td>
                              <td width="15%" class="rsData1">02/10/2012 06:09:50</td>
                              <td width="10%" class="rsData1">
                                 <div align="center"><input type="button" name="loadStatus" valign="middle" size="10" value="PENDING" onclick="javascript:getDetail('BID','9918', 'PENDING')" class="PENDING"></div>
                              </td>
                              <td width="24%" class="rsData1"><br>
                              </td>
                              <td width="29%" class="rsData1">
                                 02/10/2012 06:10:14                                                
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">BID</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">9919</td>
                              <td width="6%" class="rsData2" valign="middle"></td>
                              <td width="16%" class="rsData2" valign="middle">XYZ</td>
                              <td width="15%" class="rsData2">02/10/2012 06:11:55</td>
                              <td width="10%" class="rsData2">
                                 <div align="center"><input type="button" name="loadStatus" valign="middle" size="10" value="PENDING" onclick="javascript:getDetail('BID','9919', 'PENDING')" class="PENDING"></div>
                              </td>
                              <td width="24%" class="rsData2"><br>
                              </td>
                              <td width="29%" class="rsData2">
                                 02/10/2012 06:12:15                                                
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
            </TD>
            </TR>
            <tr>
               <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
            </tr>
            <TR>
               <TD></TD>
            </TR>
         </TABLE>
         <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="LOAD_ID" value="" />    
         <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="uiStatus" value="" />      
      </FORM>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I know basics jquery , but i could not able to think logic and implement for this ,anyone who are expert please help me.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //i can do for single columns it works, but confused what to i have multiple columns
  var seen = {};
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});
});
```

Comment: how will you choose which row will remain?

Comment: @SamTengWong  If the STATUS column values is not PARTIAL and CA column values are not of the same name.  Need to put unique row based on CA & STATUS column whereas only for PARTIAL status.

Comment: ca column group by at server side..

Comment: no, in your example there are three of them right? how will I choose which one will remain?

Comment: @SantoshRamKunjir thanks but you can see LD column it is unique, group by wont work, I already tried to solve from query, at last thought to handle this from UI

Comment: @SamTengWong As your wish, you can choose anyone you feel comfortable. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add a class for little selector simplification say "mytable"

You can use following javascript for your solution:

```
var seen = [];

function pushDataInSeen(ca, status) {
    var alreadyThere = false;
    var i = 0
    for (i = 0; i < seen.length; i++) {
        var theObj = seen[i];
        if ((theObj.ca == ca) && (theObj.status == status) && (status == 'partial')) {
            alreadyThere = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!alreadyThere) {
        seen.push({
            "ca": ca,
            "status": status
        });
    }
    return !alreadyThere;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var removal = [];
    $('table.mytable tr').each(function(index) {
        if (index) {
            /* skip the first one for header as per the html structure */
            var ca = $("td:nth-child(1)", $(this)).text().trim().toLowerCase();
            var status = $("td:nth-child(6) input", $(this)).val().toLowerCase();
            if (!pushDataInSeen(ca, status)) {
                removal.push(index + 1);
            }
        }
    });

    removal.reverse();
    for (var i = 0; i < removal.length; i++) {
        $('table.mytable tr:nth-child(' + removal[i] + ')').remove();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you. But your output is not as expected output. If you read the description above , i have asked to only apply this logic for PARTIAL status  column. Expected output: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mTnu5.png

Comment: @Ashu I skipped partial keyword thing earlier, please use above code, now it will work.

Comment: Update, i missed to ask:   The COUNT columns values should be sum up at the same time and displayed  when  extra duplicate rows removed. Eg.http://i.stack.imgur.com/KfQW2.png

Answer (score 0):

Inside your .each loop, add:

```
var tdElements = $(this).find('td').get();
```

This will get an array of all the td elements in order of appearance, then you can loop through and extract the text of the td elements you want.